# Can't update loglevel at runtime at Docker with NLog

Tags: c#, docker, nlog

I have a few services, that nicely updated their log level automatically when the config value Alpha.LogLevel was updated (as usual debug run). But when I try to update their log level in runtime at Docker, they don't change it (but change it after reboot, so the config is correct).

My config example:

```
"Alpha": {
    "LogLevel": "Info",
...
"NLog": {
    "throwConfigExceptions": true,
    "autoReload": true,
    "internalLogToConsole": true,
    "extensions": [
      { "assembly": "SumoLogic.Logging.NLog" },
      { "assembly": "NLog.Extensions.Logging" }
    ],
    "targets": {
      "async": true,
      "fileTarget": {
        "type": "File",
        "fileName": "${gdc:assemblyFolder}/logs/${gdc:item=serviceName}/${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}/${gdc:item=serviceLogName}-${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.log",
        "layout":
        "${longdate:universalTime=true}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${scopeproperty:correlationId}|${message:exceptionSeparator=\r\n:withException=true}"
      },
      "errorFileTarget": {
        "type": "File",
        "fileName": "${gdc:assemblyFolder}/logs/${gdc:item=serviceName}/${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}/${gdc:item=serviceLogName}-${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}_errors.log",
        "layout":
        "${longdate:universalTime=true}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${scopeproperty:correlationId}|${message:exceptionSeparator=\r\n:withException=true}"
      },
      "consoleTarget": {
        "type": "Console",
        "layout": "${longdate:universalTime=true}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${scopeproperty:correlationId}|${message:exceptionSeparator=\r\n:withException=true}"
      },
    "rules": [
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "ruleName": "consoleBase",
        "minLevel": "Error",
        "writeTo": "consoleTarget"
      },
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "ruleName": "errorFile",
        "minLevel": "Error",
        "writeTo": "errorFileTarget"
      },
      {
        "logger": "Alpha.*",
        "ruleName": "Alpha",
        "minLevel": "${configsetting:item=Alpha.LogLevel}",
        "writeTo": "fileTarget, consoleTarget"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I tried to remove ${configsetting:item=Alpha.LogLevel} and type just level name here, but it doesn't work too.

Comment: Please update your question with details of how you load the NLog-configuration from `appsetting.json`-file. Also explain what is meant by "update their log level in runtime at Docker", are you modifying the deployed `appsetting.json`-file or environment variable or something else ? (Notice the idea with docker-images is that they stay immutable, also after deployment)